# SOLR : Matching Street Types

Tags: solr

I am doing address matching in SOLR and for most part it is working fine. I have a situation where I would like return the same value for the following two cases:

```
10 SMITH COURT REDBANK PLAINS QLD
10 SMITH CT REDBANK PLAINS QLD
```

The street type abbreviation `CT = COURT`.

One option I have tried is to have both the records in SOLR, but that just leads to duplication of a lot of data. I have ~30 million records, but these could be halved if there is a way in SOLR to match as explained above.

Any suggestions how to handle this issue?

Comment: you can add the synonym as CT = COURT....Did you tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms allow users to find documents through multiple terms that might not have been used in the original document definition.

You can try using `solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory`

For more details on the synonym filter please refer to [the documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html).

Comment: Thank you. I used it and it is working now.